# .Net core app build error in Openshift Online

Tags: c#, .net, openshift, .net-core

I have a repo https://github.com/kuntal-b/netCore and I want to host this with openshift

but its an error

```
---> Building application ...
Couldn't find 'project.json' in '.'
error: build error: non-zero (13) exit code from registry.access.redhat.com/dotnet/dotnetcore-11-rhel7@sha256:7c775cc11b280105f51bf2622ed79036c7f961e1cb9db23c4b17c66606154f7b
```

Comment: Hi! i don't know anything about C#, but the container seems to need a project.json in . directory to be able to build your project, your project.json is in netCore/project.json.
Try moving it back in .

Comment: Please see the repo again.did you mean that?but not working.

Comment: Yes working.but is that correct way to do that?what I upload upload previously that original structure created in vs2015 and I copy the project.json in root .

Comment: I think i found the proper way, and posted it as an answer, there is an ENV var to setup :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [image github's README](https://github.com/redhat-developer/s2i-dotnetcore/blob/master/1.1/README.md) you just have to specify the PATH to your project.json file with DOTNET_STARTUP_PROJECT.

Examples :

With standalone `s2i`

```
s2i build https://github.com/kuntal-b/netCore.git -e DOTNET_STARTUP_PROJECT=src/netCore dotnet/dotnetcore-11-rhel7 my-donet-app
```

Openshift Client `oc`

```
oc new-app registry.access.redhat.com/dotnet/dotnetcore-11-rhel7~https://github.com/kuntal-b/netCore.git -e DOTNET_STARTUP_PROJECT=src/netCore --name=my-donet-app
```

Hope it helped :)